# iOS Developer Bundle ID & App Name Already in Use

Tags: ios, bundle-identifier

The company I work for created an app, we uploaded it to the app and it was rejected for some Metadata. No big deal really, except that management then decided to build a new version of the app and had us delete the one submitted.

So when I go to add a new app, the same app, just a new version I get the error

- The Bundle ID you entered has already been used.
- The App Name you entered has already been used.

Can we undelete the other app and somehow replace it, or do we just have to wait (how long?) to upload the new one using the same Bundle ID and App Name?

Comment: The answer is to create a new bundleID, update your app, and submit a new app with a slightly chanced name to Apple. No other options as far as I have seen.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is to create a new bundleID, update your app, and submit a new app with a slightly chanced name to Apple. No other options as far as I have seen.

Answer (score 2):

I created my iOS App ID and immediately after tried to register my app, but received the error message "The Bundle ID you entered has already been used." I tried again a few hours later -- by then, Apple had logged me out so I had to log back in.

When I tried again, it worked with no errors. Not sure if it was the time delay or the log out / back in.

Comment: 5 years later and still valid, signing out worked for me! :D

Answer (score 0):

There's a bug or 'trick' on iTunes Connect that let's you use the same name after you have deleted it.

Full details here: https://hesh.am/2012/01/25/recovering-a-deleted-app-name-in-itunes-connect/

Comment: Use http://web.archive.org/web/20120611041128/http://hesh.am/2012/01/recovering-a-deleted-app-name-in-itunes-connect/. Good example of why external links are not great on SO.

Answer (score 0):

bundleID is unique ID by which application can identified. If bundleID is already exist then you delete that bundleID first.

Comment: But the bundle ID doesn't exists, for sure - I receive it *every time* for every new app I'm trying to add