# How to completely remove bundle id in iOS development?

Tags: ios, bundle-identifier

How can I reuse the bundle ID I have created for the app ID? I even delete the associated app ID but the bundle ID still unavailable.Does it to say bundle ID couldn't be removed completely once created?

Comment: You mean, deleting it from developer portal, i.e, App IDs ?

Comment: In developer portal it's cannot be reused once created.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The bundle id can't be reused as exact. For example `com.abc.xxx` can be used only once. If you had created this app Id from one account, you can't create the same app Id from the other account. However, you will still be able to create a new one as `com.abc.xxx1` like or so. There should be atleast 1 character difference in the app Id's

If you want to delete an app ID, follow these steps:

1. Open https://developer.apple.com and enter using your credentials.
2. Click on Identifiers under the Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles section.
3. Now click on the App ID you want to Delete.
4. Click on Remove next to Edit your App ID Configuration.
5. Again click on Remove in the confirmation message that opens.

Comment: This process does not work for local test applications deployed with free provisioning profiles. In this workflow, the developer does not have a paid Apple developer account. Therefore they get no portal login to maintain previously used bundle ID's. This persists even if you upgrade to a paid account. I've yet to find a way to 'clean up' free-provisioned bundle ID's.

Comment: And it is a time delay before you can use deleted BundleID at another account. https://stackoverflow.com/a/23330489/5790492

Comment: Any feedback on how to solve _This persists even if you upgrade to a paid account. I've yet to find a way to 'clean up' free-provisioned bundle ID's. _ is highly appreciated @ShaunO

Comment: My developer account is long expired, and the developer portal does not let me access the App IDs page, but xcode had no problem in registering a new id on that account, without my interaction, it registered a bundle id on the wrong account, without asking me first if I wanted that. I opened the xcode page to select the bundle-id and team, and before I had time to select  anything, it started registering with the last account that I had used.

Comment: so how do to remove a bundle ID from a free profile?

Comment: If you have the situation where you had a free acount and then register a different paid account (which is what Apple in fact reccomends if you have a company) then see the solution from ackh explained below. That worked for me. Looks like it's an Xcode bug.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what your exact scenario is, you didn't provide enough information to know that. However, I came across a similar problem which was as follows:

Some time ago I registered a new Apple Account and created an iOS app with it. I did not pay for that, i.e. the app could only ever be used for 7 days. I've never submitted that app to the app store. Nonetheless, the bundle identifier of the app was associated with that particular account.

Some time later I registered another Apple Account. This time with a payed subscription. When I attempted to sign the app I created with the first account, Xcode complained as follows:

> Failed to register bundle identifier. The app identifier "xy" cannot be registered to your development team because it is not available.

and

> No profiles for 'xy' were found. Xcode couldn't file any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'xy'.

It seems that the bundle identifier gets strictly associated with the provisioning profile of the first account. The way to solve this is to delete that particular provisioning profile. You can do so by going to the following folder and deleting the corresponding file in that folder:

```
~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/
```

Comment: Wow looks like this is an Xcode bug rather than an issue with the Apple Developer accounts. Error message is totaling misleading. I was going crazy trying to figure this out.

Comment: @JamesXabregas Yes, that behavior of Xcode is highly questionable and it took me a while to figure out how to solve that issue. I haven't opened a bug report with Apple though. However, I was sure somebody else would encounter this which is why I added my approach as answer here.