# To change the bundle identifier of the my ios application

Tags: ios, swift, bundle-identifier

I am new in IOS development. I want to change the bundle identifier of my IOS project.

I have tried few things but it gives me errors.
I want a complete guide to change the bundle id successfully.
when I try to upload the application to app-store to get error
The Bundle ID you entered has already been used.

Comment: How did you manage to get a duplicate bundle id? Did you copy someone else's code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9742576/ios-developer-bundle-id-app-name-already-in-use

Answer (score 0):

- Open you project with XCode
- Select the top project item (probably your project name) in the
  project navigator at the left.
- Select TARGETS -> General. Bundle
  Identifier is found under Identity.

Answer (score -3):

Open your Apple developer account create unique bundle-id. Then create provisioning profile for that. Now, you can use that bundle-id.