# how to change the bundle id without deleting the data

Tags: ios, swift, bundle-identifier

I am new in IOS development.
Can changing the bundle id will delete all the files in the project I get this message as shown in the following image url

can pressing the continue button will delete the file or data in the my project.

Image url : https://drive.google.com/file/d/13eWo4UyQ8em3YpOgt8DYAtpQAjYv9f8A/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You won't lose any files or data.   What the message says that you have changes that aren't committed to your version control system (probably Git), so if you proceed with the rename you won't be able to undo that action. If your changes were all committed then you would be able to undo the rename by checking out the old files,

Comment: In the future you should just edit your previous post, 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60630155/to-change-the-bundle-identifier-of-the-my-ios-application

Answer (score 1):

The message in the image is showing that your project has some uncommitted
 changes means the repo is not updated.

Changing bundle identifier will not affect your data. it will occur only when you will upload your app to already existing app to appstore. Basically it will show that you have no app registered with this bundle ID other than this you'll not get any error or data loss.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to understand that `BundleId` and `ProjectName` are different things. You trying to rename the project here and confirming the action with pressing `Continue` button It will rename the project file and also necessary linked file paths.

Means you can access the project with the new name, it won't delete any project files. However, you can still see the same `BundleId` in `General` section.

> Project Target -> General -> Bundle Identifier

```
I also suggest you to `Commit` your changes before proceeding to project rename.
```